# Horizontal Panning D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am new to D3 and I am actually trying horizontal panning options for a bar chart. I have tried the following [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nverba/Mf457/11/) where horizantal panning works perfectly but there are certain problems that i could see. As I want to limit the panning with respect to the data that are present within a specific bound in the graph (doesn't want to pan horizontally to infinity) Please help me through this. Are there any working examples available online. Thank you.

JS code:

```
    var data = [
      {"date":"2011-12-31","num":5},
      {"date":"2012-01-05","num":10},
      {"date":"2012-01-10","num":22},
      {"date":"2012-01-15","num":72},
      {"date":"2012-01-20","num":87},
      {"date":"2012-01-25","num":90}
];


function draw(){

    var location = "#post"
    var month_names = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var graph_width = 500;
    var graph_height = 200;

    var values = _.pluck(data, 'num');
    var max_val = d3.max(values);
    var v_scale = graph_height / max_val;
    var data_counts = data.length;
    var bar_width = graph_width / data_counts;
    var minDate = new Date(data[0]["date"]);
    var maxDate = new Date(data[data.length - 1]["date"]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, max_val])
        .range([graph_height, 0]);

    console.log(minDate);
    var x = d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]).range([0, graph_width]);


    var chart = d3.select(location).append("svg")
        .attr("class", "chart")
        .attr("width", graph_width + 20)
        .attr("height", graph_height + 20).
        call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom));

    var lines = chart.selectAll("line");

    var lines_y = lines
        .data(x.ticks(5))
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("x1", x)
        .attr("x2", x)
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return graph_height - 20 - d;})
        .attr("y2", graph_height)
        .style("stroke", "#ccc");

    var lines_x = lines
        .data(y.ticks(10))
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("x2", graph_width)
        .attr("y1", y)
        .attr("y2", y)
        .style("stroke", "#ccc");

    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x);
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

    chart.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "xaxis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,200)")
        .call(xAxis);

    chart.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "yaxis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(25,0)")
        .call(yAxis);

    var rect = chart.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data).enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {return x(new Date(d["date"])) + 20;})
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {return graph_height - (d["num"] * v_scale);})
        .attr("width", x(new Date(data[1]["date"])))
        .attr("height", function(d, i) {return d["num"] * v_scale;});

    function zoom() {
        chart.select(".xaxis").call(xAxis);
        chart.select(".yaxis").call(yAxis);
        chart.selectAll(".chart rect").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0] + ",0)scale(" + d3.event.scale + ", 1)");
    }

    }
draw();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict the panning, simply check the value of the translation before applying it. Note that the translation value will be the inverse of the direction that you're panning in. That is, if you pan in the positive `x` direction, the translation value for `x` will be negative.

The code will look something like this.

```
function zoom() {
    if(d3.event.translate[0] > -100) {
        // translate
    }
}
```

The actual value (`-100` above) will depend on what you actually want. You might want to pass a value in your input domain to restrict the panning to e.g. the edge of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general purpose solution for anyone who needs it. By looking at the range rather than the domain of the X scale, this works with date/time axes too.

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1,Infinity])
    .on("zoom", function () {
        var t = zoom.translate(),
            max = d3.max(x.range()),
            tx = Math.max( Math.min(0, t[0]), width - max * zoom.scale() );

        zoom.translate([ tx, t[1] ]);

        draw();
    });
```